# Creating nested folders in one go - OneDrive API

Tags: onedrive

The api for creating folders for OneDrive reads as follows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_post_children?view=odsp-graph-online

As far as I can see (and have tested in multiple ways using an array of folder objects, etc), that endpoint does not support creating a nested folder-structure in one go, like so: **"foo/bar/baz"**, which should create all three folders in that structure.

*It works fine with chained paths with the Dropbox API for instance - so hoping it would be possible for OneDrive too.*

Are there alternatives for this in the API, or do we have to send one request pr folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work ok in OneDrive Consumer (it might in OneDrive Business, but I haven't tried it):

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/foo/bar/baz

{
  "folder": {}
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Trick was to remove "name" parameter in the body (wich was included in a query I had) and to switch from POST to PATCH.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Brad where is this stated? I can't find it in their documentation. The closest I could find was this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_update?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: @Brad Worked like a charm! Thanks for saving a lot of time and efforts!